# why string.length return undefined?

Tags: javascript

In the popup window, selText does have the value "great," but the length is always `undefined`. Something related with the encoding of the string?

```
var selText = document.getSelection(); //suppose "great" is selected
alert( "selected ->" + selText + " len is " + selText.length);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because you're getting a DOM selection object instead of a String. To get the text, call `toString()`.

```
var selText = document.getSelection().toString();
```

The reason the string successfully shows up in the alert, is that the concatenation causes an implicit `toString()` to occur.

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection) states.

> In the above example, selObj is
>   automatically "converted" when passed
>   to window.alert. However, to use a
>   JavaScript String property or method
>   such as length or substr, you must
>   manually call the toString method.
>   -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.getSelection

It's suggesting you call `document.getSelection().ToString().length;`

Comment: The function the MDN docs are referring to is `window.getSelection()`, not `document.getSelection()`, which is not universally supported and now replaced in all current browsers by `window.getSelection()`. Also, it's `toString()` rather than `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated method document.getSelection() Try use window.getSelection().

```
var selText = window.getSelection().toString();
        if(selText)
        {
            alert( "selected ->" + selText + " len is " + (selText.length - 1));
        }
```